# Number of permutations with repetition of all the sets whose elements sum is equal or lower to $N$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Let's consider a certain number of integers (e.g. $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$) and another integer number $N$ (e.g. $40$).
The integers can be arrenged in sets of fixed number of digit $K$ (e.g. for $K$=$3$, the sets can contain three numbers of the avaiable integers at most).

Does exist a function which returns the number of permutations with repetition of all the sets whose elements sum is equal or lower to $N$?

I have acknowledged that this problem is close to the subset sum problem, but I couldn't find any generating function which exactely satisfy my quesition (such as the ones described in https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SubsetSumProblem.html). I have developed an algorithm which returns all the possible sets, but I would like to know if it is possible to obtain the number without runnign the code.

Thanks

Comment: So, to confirm, you are asking for the number of integral solutions to $\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k\leq n\\ x_i\in \{1,2,\dots,10\}~~~\forall i\end{cases}$?  Consider stars and bars along with inclusion-exclusion based around having violated any of the upper bound conditions.

Comment: I confirm your answer.